# Error nonetype object has no attribute text while scraping via beautiful soup 4 python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some info using beautiful soup in python using python webscraping. Here is the section.

```
<div class="result-value" data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1">
<span data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1.0">751</span>
<span class="result-value-unit" data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1.1">KB</span>
</div


Snap: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d349tb3f22o0wyf/4.png?dl=0
```

Code I am using is this

```
Sizeofweb=""
try:
    Sizeofweb= soup.find('span', {'data-reactid': ".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1.0"}).text
    print Sizeofweb
except StandardError as e:
    converted_date="Error was {0}".format(e)
    print converted_date
```

Error

```
nonetype object has no attribute text
```

I have tried this but didnt work. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me -

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_str = """
<div class="result-value" data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1">
<span data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1.0">751</span>
<span class="result-value-unit" data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1.1">KB</span>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str,"lxml")

Sizeofweb = soup.find('span', {'data-reactid': ".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1.0"}).text

print Sizeofweb
```

Output

```
751
```

One thing I noticed is the last div tag close is missing the close angle bracket - ">"

Dunno how you've done it but this works for me...

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that you used the "lxml" parser.  Different parser's will handle the HTML structure differently, and one parser may handle absent closing tags better than another.  BeautifulSoup's documentation highlights the differences between different parsers - https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use.

Comment: good point @Jalepeno112 putting in a decent html string always is much more sensible though...did not know this one thanks!